# High charts Tool tip is not supporting in IE10 and IE8 and Mozilla with more data

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, highcharts

This is the Bar chart i am using and here this is code with data: 
In this code i have more data which is shown in the tool tip  but problem is some data is showing in the tool tip and the remaining data is not showing in the tooltip:

This is the screen shot show in google chrome with complete data formate in only one line :  [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Network Availaibility (Without Exclusions) - %',
                    'Network Availaibility (Without Exclusions) - %',
                    'Network Availaibility (Without Exclusions) - %',
                    'Network Availaibility (Without Exclusions) - %'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: '13-Jan',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]

            }, {
                name: '13-Feb',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]

            }, {
                name: '13-Mar',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3]

            }, {
                name: '13-Apr',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5]

            },
            {
                name: '13-May',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]

            }, {
                name: '13-Jul',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]

            }, {
                name: '13-Aug',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3]

            }, {
                name: '13-Sep',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5]

            },
            {
                name: '13-Oct',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5]

            },
            {
                name: '13-Nov',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]

            }, {
                name: '13-Dec',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]

            },{
                name: '14-Jan',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]

            }, {
                name: '14-Feb',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]

            }, {
                name: '14-Mar',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3]

            }, {
                name: '14-Apr',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5]

            },
            {
                name: '14-May',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]

            }, {
                name: '14-Jul',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]

            }, {
                name: '14-Aug',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3]

            }
            ]
        });
    });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the screen shot which is in internet explorer with irregular data which is showing incomplete data in **IE10** and **IE8**  and **mozilla** also: 
   [image]

and this is the js fiddle link please load in **mozilla** and **ie10** : http://jsfiddle.net/2pv3tpmd/1/

[image]

This is in IE10 ,,please check :

this is in Mozilla : please check :

[image]

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with rendering tables in IE8, simply set styles: `white-space:nowrap`, like this:

```
        pointFormat: '<tr style="white-space:nowrap"><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2pv3tpmd/6/

About Firefox (?) - works fine for me, tested with v32

**Edit:**
Screenshot:[image]

**Edit 2:**
Screenshot:[image]

Comment: nope ...in IE10 and IE8 and Mozilla  i have Mozilla v31.0 and IE10 and IE 8 and i tried with your updated code .. still i am facing the same issue..please suggest

Comment: Works fine with 8.0.6.6001, see above screenshot. I guess you are using some developer tools to test IE8, that may be the reason. Firefox also works, I can attach screenshot too.

Comment: hi ,yes i added code you provided but sometimes mouse over gets irregular values means line by line and sometimes mouse over will get regular values .same line......and how did u added the screen shot in this comment box ?

Comment: i will attach my screen shot..in comment that i have taken

Comment: I added my screenshot in answer, not comment. Anyway, maybe you have some CSS which prevents my styles? My demo doesn't work for you?

Comment: yes it works but some times it shows the values in tool tip in same line but some times it shows values line by line ...when mouse over ..did u checked in mozilla

Comment: please check i have added the screen show which is IE10

Comment: i have added the screen shots which is done in mozilla and IE10...please chech

Comment: Just tested with IE10, my demo works (see attached above screenshot). Recreate issue in jsFiddle, otherwise I can' help you. As I can see from your screenshot from FF, it works too.

Comment: hi ..@pawel...  one help ...for the bars ..individual color will not come ..it is coming same colors for the two bars...how to make the individual color for the bars ..please help

Comment: hi ..@pawel... one help ...for the bars ..individual color will not come ..it is coming same colors for the two bars...how to make the individual color for the bars

Comment: You know, sending every hour the same comment, won't wake me up and won't speed up my answer.. ;) Anyway, use `colorByPoint` option.

Comment: i have added      series.color    in tooltip ..but the same colors are reflecting and please tell where to add..

Comment: (sorry if i disturb ...)i mean the bar color has to change according to value..and in plot options colorbypoint is added but for the entire bars is showing one color and another entire bars is showing another color ..i want  with different color for different bar ..change according to the value

Comment: Then for each point set specific color, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847996/highcharts-ohlc-can-i-provide-color-information-for-each-point-with-json-data) - it's exactly the same issue.. just don't add lines: `Highcharts.wrap(...)` because you don't use OHLC series.

Comment: And one help ...how to change the y-axis values from this range to this range .. in the above graph y-axis value is from 0-125  and how to change the range of y-axis from 0 to 50 to  100 default ...

Comment: hi , @pawel ...i got one issue after have seen the highcharts link in this : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPosition .....i have added the interval from 90 to 100 but the issue is when i have the value 99.95,99.96,99.97,99.98,99.99    : for this values in the tool tip ...its showing approximate value i.e.100%...please help how to display the exact value in the tool tip..

Comment: Use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) or [tooltip.pointFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat).

Comment: Thanks...i have added point.y:.1f  ....now i changed to this point.y  ...its showing the exact value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '{point.key}<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
```

if this didn't work either then try zooming out of your browser window a bit by holding down ctrl key and scrolling down (just in case its some resolution issue)

Comment: yes, tried by zooming and zooming out ..same issue please check the jsfiddle link that i provide above ..and i also i modified with your code ...not solved ..

Comment: try the updated answer..and sorry jsfiddle doesnt seem to work on my ie

Comment: other wise please open in MOZILLA . .and check

Comment: Hi, did any one got solution ...for tooltip issue in mozilla and ie